# Why is threading increasing execution time c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

Using two threads to print numbers which increases time then using single loop to print I know that synchronization is increasing time but in my code how can I increase time and stop threads to print duplicate numbers ? Is there Anyway ?

```
class Program
{
    public static int count=0;
    public static List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
    public static int semaphore=0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(i.ToString());
        }

       Console.WriteLine("Before start thread");

       Thread tid1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThread.Thread1));
       Thread tid2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThread.Thread1));

       tid1.Start();
       tid2.Start();
    }
}
  public class MyThread
{
    public static object locker = new object();

    public static void Thread1()
    {
        for (; Program.count < Program.numbers.Count;)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Program.numbers[Program.count]);
                Program.count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// this is faster than threading why ?

```
foreach (var item in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

average time with thread is 1.5ms and loop is 0.6ms

Comment: I know that time is increasing due to waiting lock of resource .But in my case I have to use synchronization . Is there anyway to increase execution time ? without synchronization in my code ?

Comment: Well, more threads than processor cores increases the execution time due to the context switching, but not by that much. If you want to avoid synchronization caused delays than just don't use threading code that needs synchronization - design your application in a way that everything parallelizable can be executed without synchronization.

Comment: In my problem can you think of a way to do it in parallel ?

Comment: Threading does not necessarily increase the performance. The actual resources you have to compute is the parallel processing unit. If your parallel processing unit are all busy, then making more thread will *decrease* the performance. The second factor is the context switch. The more thread you have, the more often you do your context switch. If your Thread computation time is relatively low as compared to the context switch time, then you have a worse performance with multi-threading. And the another is of course shared-resource. If your shared resources are often accessed by the two threads

Comment: Then the higher is the possibility for them to wait for one another.

Comment: @phpnet Your problem is not CPU-bound - it is more of an IO task, And it is sequential in its nature. So there is nothing you can do here.

Comment: There are, like, 30 instructions in your thread code that we can see in the C code and 300,000 in locked-up system calls.  Hopeless waste of threads.

Comment: ' The more thread you have, the more often you do your context switch' - this is not, in general, correct.

Answer (score 5):

Multi-threading does not guarantee increase in the performance.

**Firstly**, the actual resources that really matter in multi-processing is the number of *parallel processing unit* and whether they are *busy or not* - and *not* the number of *threads*. If your *parallel processing units* are all busy, or if

```
the number of thread > number of parallel processing unit
```

then making more thread will *decrease* the performance, *not* increasing it.

**Secondly** is the *context switch* factor. The more threads you have, likely the more often you do your *context switches*. Therefore, if your `Thread` computation time is relatively low as compared to the context switch time, then you have a *worse* performance with multi-threading.

And **thirdly**, it is also affected by the *shared-resources* (or *synchronization*) factor: whether your shared resources are often accessed by the multiple threads - where they will need to *wait* for one another thus resulting in *slower* execution.

In **your case**, it seems to be the *third* case, as mentioned by @Peter. This is because you have global `count` variable (not local) which are shared and *must be accessed by every single Thread* to complete your task. That is, *you have a task that is **sequential** by nature*. This makes your execution time with multiple threads worse than your execution time with a single thread.

For this case, you can expect to have better result with Multithreading if you have task which is not sequential by nature (that is, can be split and done independently before collecting the results), then you can try to look for `Parallel.For` to execute your tasks.

For instance: you have local `count` for each thread, and at the end of the process you sum them.

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 threads which are waiting on each other because you lock syncing between the threads:

```
        lock (locker)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Program.numbers[Program.count]);
            Program.count++;
        }
```

The thread switches and waits result in longer execution time.

Comment: I know that @Peter but how to avoid synchronization ?

Comment: You should use only local variables in your MyThread function instead of statics which you are using now.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers suggest, context switching and lock take time decreasing performance. So, if you wish to get faster processing you need to remove locks and shared resources. 
In addition to that, your test is not good for exploring the multithreading because in addition to your explicit lock there is also implicit lock inside the **Console.WriteLine** (Console is also a shared resource).

To improve performance you need to remove locks.

So, if for example you run two threads where first thread is processing only the half of your numbers array (say, odd numbers) and the second thread is processing the second half (e.g. even numbers) and instead of console.WriteLine you do something which does not use shared resources, then you will see the gain in performance.

Consider the following example (I changed your code):

```
class Program
{
    public static int count = 0;
    public static List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
    public static System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add(i.ToString());
        }

        // First test - process nummbers in current thread
        sw.Start();
        foreach (var item in numbers)
        {
            DoSomethingWithTheNumber(item);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("foreach in main thread took, ticks: "+sw.ElapsedTicks);

        // Second test - process nummbers in 2 threads with lock
        Thread tid1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThread.Thread1));
        Thread tid2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThread.Thread1));
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        tid1.Start();
        tid2.Start();
        tid1.Join();
        tid2.Join();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("for in 2 threads with lock took, ticks: " + sw.ElapsedTicks);

        // Third test - process nummbers in 2 threads without lock
        // first thread processes odd numbers, second processes odd numbers
        Thread tid1A = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThreadWithoutLock.ThreadOddNumbers));
        Thread tid2A = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThreadWithoutLock.ThreadEvenNumbers));
        sw.Reset();
        sw.Start();
        tid1A.Start();
        tid2A.Start();
        tid1A.Join();
        tid2A.Join();
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("for in 2 threads without lock took, ticks: " + sw.ElapsedTicks);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void DoSomethingWithTheNumber(string number)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(number);
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    public class MyThread
    {
        public static object locker = new object();

        public static void Thread1()
        {
            for (; Program.count < Program.numbers.Count; )
            {
                lock (locker)
                {
                    if(Program.count < Program.numbers.Count)
                        DoSomethingWithTheNumber(Program.numbers[Program.count]);
                    Program.count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyThreadWithoutLock
    {
        public static void ThreadOddNumbers()
        {
            for (int i=1; i < Program.numbers.Count; i=i+2)
            {
                DoSomethingWithTheNumber(Program.numbers[i]);
            }
        }
        public static void ThreadEvenNumbers()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Program.numbers.Count; i = i + 2)
            {
                DoSomethingWithTheNumber(Program.numbers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:
foreach in main thread took, ticks: 2337320
for in 2 threads with lock took, ticks: 2351632
for in 2 threads without lock took, ticks: 1176403

You can see that the last option with two threads without locking really gives you 2 times faster processing.

Answer (score 1):

The following code while still thread safe, it's faster because it is lock-free. I replaced `lock` keyword with `Interlocked.Increment`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int count = 0;
        public static List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
        public static int semaphore = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                numbers.Add(i.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Before start thread");
            Thread tid1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThread.Thread1));
            Thread tid2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThread.Thread1));

            tid1.Start();
            tid2.Start();

            tid1.Join();
            tid2.Join();
        }
    }
    public class MyThread
    {

        public static void Thread1()
        {
            int nextIndex;
            while ((nextIndex = Interlocked.Increment(ref Program.count)) <= Program.numbers.Count)
            { 
               Console.WriteLine(Program.numbers[nextIndex - 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```